# How to change CakePHP 4 password hashing algorithm

Tags: cakephp, hash, passwords

My question is in the title: How can I change the default password hashing algorithm in CakePHP v4 to say SHA2-512? Because I cannot find any reference to this in the project folder, and supposedly it's now done with a plugin. However, my plugins folder is empty, even though I have installed the required Authentication requirement with Composer.

And also, the standard salt variable that can be found in the config/app, how can I make it so that all users have different salts?

In the answer, please also make references to file locations.

Looking forward to your answer. :)

Comment: What's your ultimate goal? SHA hashes aren't normally recommended for password hashing, you typically rely on specific algorithms like Bcrypt or Argon2 where salt handling is more or less automatic.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to learn about how to store a password, so that I can have a proper users database. Why aren't SHA2 512 passwords recommended? I know absolutely nothing about Bcrypt nor argon2, that's why I'm going back to what I at least know is secure (meaning not currently broken) and I trust.
Plus, the fact that there is a "salt" variable in the php settings in cakePHP, seems REALLY dodgy, because it implies the same salt will be applied to every user.

Comment: Fair enough. Regarding your questions: 1) Some hashes are specifically designed to be slow to calculate, that comes in handy for this purpose (as opposed to, e.g., verify a corrupted download, where you want speed). 2) CakePHP salt is not the salt being added to hashed passwords.

Comment: Okay... And if that salt variable is not what's added to the passwords, then what exactly is that for? And is it the same for every cakePHP v4 project? Because that would make even less sense. 
Quote from the php file, a comment that is above the variable: 
salt - A random string used in security hashing methods.
     *   The salt value is also used as the encryption key.
     *   You should treat it as extremely sensitive data.

Comment: CakePHP makes use of hashing in several different places. For instance, the CSRF middleware if I recall correctly.

Comment: A random salt is being generated when creating the project via composer, it is unique per project. If you want to check where exactly it is being used, search the source code for `getSalt()` (besides encryption keys it's mostly used for HMAC hashes that are used as tokens and signatures).

Comment: `how can I make it so that all users have different salts?` this is already the case, by default. CakePHP just uses [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) under the hood. The salt you've found is not related to user authentication. It's probably best to [follow a tutorial](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html) and use the code in its default form before trying to modify how it works, especially to modify it based on what looks like a misunderstanding.

Comment: I have followed that tutorial, this is an excerpt from the tutorial articles creation, and it bricked my WAMP server. So... :)

Comment: `this is an excerpt from the tutorial articles creation` what is the “this” in that statement? Following a tutorial is not going to have any effect on wamp, there’s unstated assumptions/confusion/mistakes there - please edit the question to address (all) comments.

Comment: Just to emphasise, SHA* is **not** appropriate for hashing passwords because it is way too fast, you can calculate several Giga SHA-512 per sec with common hardware, this makes brute-forcing way too easy. This is why there are password-hash functions like Argon2 or BCrypt, they offer a cost factor which controls the time necessary to do a calculation. They are used automatically by [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).